# FromQuaternion and QuaternionQ not working symbolically?

Tags: quaternions

How can I get *Mathematica* to work with quaternions symbolically? I want to do some quaternion math without defining the actual coefficients, and then extract the coefficients from the resulting quaternion. For some reason, however, `FromQuaternion` only seems to work when values rather than symbols are the coefficients. The following simple examples illustrate the problem.

If I run the following:

```
QuaternionQ[Quaternion[1, 2, 3, 4]]
FromQuaternion[Quaternion[1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

The output is as expected:

> True
>   3J + 4K + (1 + 2I)

However, if I run the following (with A0-A3 undefined):

```
QuaternionQ[Quaternion[A0, A1, A2, A3]]
FromQuaternion[Quaternion[A0, A1, A2, A3]]
```

I get

> False
>   FromQuaternion(Quaternion(A0, A1, A2, A3))

I was expecting

```
True
A0 + A1 I + A2 J + A3 K
```

However, Mathematica seems to be perfectly happy to perform functions like:

```
Quaternion[A0, A1, A2, A3] ** Quaternion[B0, B1, B2, B3]
```

With the following result

> Quaternion[A0 B0 - A1 B1 - A2 B2 - A3 B3,
>         A0 B1 + A1 B0 + A2 B3 - A3 B2,
>         A0 B2 - A1 B3 + A2 B0 + A3 B1,
>         A0 B3 + A1 B2 - A2 B1 + A3 B0]

but there seems to be no way to extract the components.

Finally, is there a function for just extracting one of the components. For instance, say `Q = Quaternion[a, b, c ,d]`. I would like a function like `I[q]` which returns `b`, `J[q]` which returns `c`, etc.

Comment: Ok, hadn't ever really looked carefully at patterns in MM. Figured out that if Q is a quaternion, then I can simply use something like Q /. Quaternion[q0_, q1_, q2_, q3_] -> q0 to extract various components. This is fine, but I still want to know why QuaternionQ and FromQuaternion don't work.

Comment: You can also use `Q[[1]]` to get the first part, `Q[[2]]` for the second etc...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A look at how `QuaternionQ[]` is defined in the package reveals the trouble: it is dependent on the private function `ScalarQ[]` for checking its individual components. `ScalarQ[]` is defined this way:

```
ScalarQ[x_]:= (NumericQ[x] && Head[x] =!= Complex)
```

It is clear that none of the components of `Quaternion[A0, A1, A2, A3]` will pass `ScalarQ[]`, and thus `QuaternionQ[]` returns `False`. Relatedly, `FromQuaternion[]` also depends on `QuaternionQ[]` (and thus `ScalarQ[]`), which is why it also doesn't work for your symbolic quaternion.

Thus, when testing for not necessarily numeric quaternions, you might want to do something like `MatchQ[Quaternion[A0, A1, A2, A3], _Quaternion]`, and use `{1, I, J, K}.(List @@ expr)` for conversion to an explicit form.

Finally, for extracting components of symbolic quaternions, look up `Part[]` or `Extract[]`.